# Is it safe to store my active FCM subscriptions using shared_preferences pacakge on both iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a flutter app where users can subscribe and unsubscribe to a FCM topic.

The list of currently subscribed topics is stored using shared_preferences packages.

The only way the app knows what subscriptions to present as options to unsubscribe to, is by looking in shared prefs.

Is there  a way a user could delete the shared prefs on iOS or android using OS data/cache clearing, while the FCM subscriptions still stay active. In this scenario my app would have 'dangling' subscriptions, because it would think it has no subscriptions, but notifications would still arrive for those topics.

Is this scenario possible on either iOS or Android?

Comment: Android, when you have active subscription and you've just uninstalled the app - you get from Google Play notification about this fact. You don't have invent the wheel again. If you want to store sensitive data you could use EncryptedSharedPreferences - https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

It is too hard but it is possible. Once upon a time, I had a similar case like yours. What I did is I created a collection on firebase database which security rules is only read, not write permission. I double-check the payment verification then I update the collection on firebase via my backend service.

DO NOT FORGET. NEVER TRUST ANY CLIENT. You have to do this through your backend services. The client has to just read.